# Opening project files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to open certain project files in eclipse. The error message says that the Project Description file(.project) is missing. However if I open up the folder using windows explorer, I am able to see the .project file. I am not sure how to resolve this, hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import manually the project in the workspace by doing:

> File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects.

Then select the root directory of your project.

After that it should be configured correctly

Comment: @javaperson, did you found this solution helpfull ?

Comment: my apologies for the late reply as I was away. Yes your solution was helpful. Thank you.